# Python nosetests cover-package and exclude some directories

Tags: python-2.7, nose

I'm using nosetests to run unit tests and show the code coverage using (python 2.7):

```
nosetests -c .noserccover -q
```

.noserccover file:

```
[nosetests]
cover-package = src/
with-coverage = 1
xcoverage-file = test_results/coverage.xml
cover-erase = 1
cover-html-dir = build/nosetests
cover-html = 1
with-xunit = 1
xunit-file = test_results/nosetests.xml
verbosity = 2
exclude-dir=src/dir_c
```

What i want is to include src/dir_a and src/dir_b but exclude src/dir_c.
I guess exclude-dir don't work if you use cover-package. When i run tests, src/dir_c is still included in the coverage.